# Module interface not updated

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a library which I use in several projects. 
In this library I have a function like:

```
public boolean update(Context context, String name,
    UpdateResponseCallback callback) 
    throws firstException {
```

Now I want to change this firstException to secondException (or to the general Exception or whatever). The build of the library works okay. And also the generated files appears to be okay.

When I move to the App which includes this library things go wrong. 
The compiler does not recognise the new/updated format. Also the quick help (mouse over) give the old interface.

I have already performed CLEAN and also File:InvalideChache but nothing helps.